# Adding permissions to member with JDA

Tags: java, permissions, discord, member, discord-jda

I want to add permissions to a member in discord using `java` and `JDA`. This will throw a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException error:`

```
jdaBot.getGuilds().get(1).getMemberById("<id>").getPermissions().add(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR);
```

Comment: Please clarify your question...

Comment: How u mean clarify it? Isn't this clear? I try to add a permission to member but with that code ^^ I get a unsportedoperationexception

Comment: First, format your code (see the Markdown rules for that). Second: what have you tried? What is the result of your research on this topic? Chances are this might already have an answer somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission list returned by `getPermissions()` on a member is [immutable](http://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/core/entities/Member.html#getPermissions-net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Channel-). You need to modify their permissions in a different way. Perhaps assign them a role which has administrator permissions?

Comment: Ok, so it isn't possible to just add some permissions to a member?